# EF code first uncertainty principle - referred entities may not get loaded

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, code-first

With automatic database *recreation*, it is uncertain whether *referred* entities will get loaded or not.

The context is EF CTP 5 and ASP.NET MVC 2. In the global.asax a database initializer is set that forces recreation of the database every time the application starts up.

Successfully retrieving an entity from a context in a controller action may still cause null reference errors when traversing references even if the references are marked as required (not null in the database). Turning off lazy loading does not make any difference.

This behaviour cannot be reproduced reliably but was observed on two different workstations (XP, 7) using Cassini.

Below are the models. Null reference exception is thrown when trying to access the `NewsProvider` property of the `NewsFeed` object. It makes no difference taking off the virtual qualifier.

```
public class NewsProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NewsFeed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a URL")]
    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "The URL is too long")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a news provider")]
    public virtual NewsProvider NewsProvider { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can I see your model? The entities that are throwing

Comment: Is this a one to many? If so I think I know the problem and can update my answer accordingly! (NewsProvider has many NewsFeed) A little more on this relationship as I think they is a going to require a small change to your Model or or the Fluent Mapping API.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but complex types can NEVER be null. So if you have any reference to a complex type (ICollection) you should initialize them from the Entity constructor.

**Example:**

```
 public class NewsProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NewsFeed
{
    public NewsFeed() {
        //Never allow NewsProvider to be null
        NewsProvider = new NewsProvider();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a URL")]
    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "The URL is too long")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a news provider")]
    public virtual NewsProvider NewsProvider { get; set; }
}
```

For more info, here is a great blog post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx

Comment: This is a good idea, thank you. It does not address the issue however, since the problem appears when you read your Product and discover that the Category property is null even though the Product row has a value in the CategoryId column.

Comment: Updated the code above to demo constructor initialization with your Model.